# Restore logger object with handler not working

Tags: python, logging

Could I store the `logger` object which contains  and restore it? As an example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('a')
        ...add a console handler and a file handler

    def function(self):
        logger = self.logger
        logger.info("INFO")
```

And the console output works well but no output in file. Only the log in the `__init__` will be outputted to the file but not the log in `function`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's an configuration issue of the logger. Especially the log level. The default is 'WARNING'. So your logger.info(..) get's ignored. You have to configure the logger.
Looke here: [Docs for logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I just omit the configuration code. And as I say, it works in `__init__` but not in `function` and works with console output handler but not file output handler. So this is exactly not a problem of configuration.